# Get return values from .dll using Ruby on rails?

Tags: c#, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ironruby

from ROR i am passing parameters to C#.net dll and doing some calculation & returning values there but i am not able to retrive those values. is it possible to get dll method return value with ROR ?

**Code:**

```
lib = WIN32OLE.new('GenerateUCNValues.GenerateUCNValues')
```

**@a=lib.GenerateUCN(obj.String.to_s,obj.id.to_i,obj.Name.to_s)**-- here i am not getting the return value (calculation operation doing good but i am not able to capture return value with ROR)

please share anyone have solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you expose your C# logic as restful web-service and make calls over the wire. Connecting via win32 is just ugly, and you won't find much help on the net to do so.